# Inversion of Control Container for PHP?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am trying to code TDD style in PHP and one of my biggest stumbling blocks (other than lack of a decent IDE) is that I have to make my own hacked together IoC container just to inject all my mock objects properly.

Has anyone used an Ioc container in PHP?  All I've been able to find is [PHP IOC on the ever-annoying phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3382.html) and it seems to have almost no documentation and not much of a following.

Comment: Have a look at my dependency injection project for PHP 5: https://github.com/jamolkhon/Sharbat

Comment: why is this question closed as off-topic? This is one of the most important topic these days

Comment: I agree, the question was if any exist, not a recommendation (and was asked six years ago). But as there is no "correct" answer I can see why it could be seen as off-topic .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played with some DI Frameworks for PHP, but I haven't used one in production. Have some links:

1. [http://www.stubbles.net/](http://www.stubbles.net) which
   I think is the oldest I tried
2. http://php.xjconf.net/
3. [FLOW3](http://flow3.typo3.org/) - I belive this one will
   become a very nice framework (its
   beta right now)

You mentioned you would use it for TDD - so maybe have a look at [Dependency Injection for Unit Tests in PHP](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2007/08/21/using-dependency-injection-for-unit-tests/)

Answer (score 6):

[Phemto](http://phemto.sourceforge.net/) is being developed again, and looks quite promising IMHO.

A few other similar projects, that you might want to look at:

[bucket](http://github.com/troelskn/bucket) (Disclaimer: I'm the principal author of this one)

The [php-port of picocontainer](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/picocontainer/php/picocontainer/trunk/container), has been around for a long time. I don't think it's being actively deveoped any more, but on the other hand, I believe that it's quite stable. It's been a long time since I looked at it though.

<del>A rather new project, I recently stumbled upon is [Crafty](http://phpcrafty.sourceforge.net/index.php). Not sure how many people uses it though.</del>

<del>I'm also watching [sphicy](http://www.beberlei.de/sphicy/), which looks interesting.</del>

Comment: Download link for Crafty is broken.  I spoke to the author, he said its a dead project, newer versions of PHP broke it due to changes in PHP reflection api.

Comment: OK - I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to try Ding (http://marcelog.github.com/Ding) which is modeled after Spring(tm) for Java. It is a complete inversion of control and dependency injection container, which also supports AOP

Answer (score 3):

What about the [Symfony Dependency Injection](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) or the PHP 5.3+ equivalent [component](https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection) from the symfony 2.0 project.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/) is another dependency injection container.

It features dependency injection through **annotations** and **minimal configuration**, here is an example:

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var Bar
     */
    private $bar;
}
```

It's very easy to use, and it integrates with Zend Framework for example.

(yes I do work on this framework)

Comment: +1 I know some guys from Zend and I know they've been working the last few years to make the concept more natural in php and more understood in the php community.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on a [PHP IoC/DI Container](http://substrate-php.org/) named Substrate for the last six months. It is still very much a work in progress but it has been [deployed in production](http://s3a.us/) for a month and a half and has been working pretty well so far.

Substrate is inspired by Spring Framework, but written with the strengths and limitations of PHP in mind. The documentation is pretty minimal at this point, but there is some [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/substrate-php/wiki/SampleCode), including a unit testing example. Is this something that you think you might be able to use for TDD?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4 has the best IoC and DI framework. if you dont mind using a framework the Laravel 4 is the way to go

Comment: It's zeh Best!!1 Zeh Best!!! Uhh … why?