# Dependency Injection: How to construct a class that depends on runtime parameters?

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, runtime, factory

I want to introduce DI to our application.

In our application, we have some generic parameters that are passed through the entire 
application, mostly via constructor parameters. 
For example the parameter *region* limits all actions to a geographic region. This parameter is gathered from user input at runtime and thereby not known at the composition root.

**How should I create classes that are always limited to work on one *region*?**

I know that I could use the factory pattern. In this case I would need to pass the DIC into the factory, which is (as far as I know) an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The factory pattern is certainly NOT an anti-pattern when working with DI, even though you will see the number of factories [decrease when you apply DI correctly](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Still in your situation a factory might not be the best approach. Typically you should [prevent letting the object graph depend on runtime data](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) and you should separate the need for that request specific data from the composition of your services.

In your case it would probably be easy to have some sort of `IRegionContext` or `IRegionManager` abstraction that allows to to get the region for the current request. This `IRegionContext` itself is a service, but contains a method that can be called by the application after the object graph is contructed:

```
public interface IRegionContext
{
    Region CurrentRegion { get; }
}
```

Application types can depend on the `IRegionContext` and in the composition root of your web application you can have a special `AspNetRegionContext` implementation that allows retrieving the region based on the current request.

Comment: Just for clarification: by anti-pattern I meant [passing the container into the factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539895/dependency-injection-how-to-pass-the-injection-container-around), not the factory itself

Comment: @user3246431: That's true. That's called the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), but you can still do factories, and the factory implementation can call the container without any problem, as long as that implementation is placed inside the Composition Root.