# How to implement a DI container?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, service, containers

I have been asking around, if it's wrong to create instances of the model layer in the controller, even though if it's hidden behind a factory like this:

```
parent::getServiceFactory()->create('Car');
```

I have got told to use A dependency injection container to initialize my controller(s). I have been googling all night, last night, I understood that Dependency injection Container (DiC) is used to create an instance of an object, and inject the needed objects into it, without doing it manually in the router - Maybe I just misunderstood the concept.

I have read this post [How to build a PHP Dependency Injection Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214408/how-to-build-a-php-dependency-injection-container), It shows the following line of code:

```
$ioc->register('database', new DatabaseServiceProvider($host, $user, $pass))
```

Now, I assume `$host, $user, $pass` are just string variables, now if I want to pass objects to a controller, how can I dynamically know which objects it needs to have injected?

Is it right to add an array of types like this?:

```
$container->register('SomeController', array('Namespace\to\Model1', 'Namespace\to\Model2'));
```

and then that container register will create an object of `SomeController`, which will have Model1, Model2 objects

Is that wrong to do? What is the correct way of using `DI` in this case? Also are Domain objects & data mappers part of the model layer?

Or is it right to initialize all controllers object in the container when the application loads, then I can easily use any controller?

Comment: You should probably first understand what a DI container is and why you would want to use it, before you attempt to actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have got told to use A dependency injection container to initialize
>   my controller(s). I have been googling all night, last night, I
>   understood that Dependency injection Container (DiC) is used to create
>   an instance of an object, and inject the needed objects into it.

That is correct.

> I have read this post How to build a PHP Dependency Injection
>   Container

Stop right there. That answer does **not** show how to build a container -- it shows how to build a [service locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator). There's a huge difference between the two:

- A service locator is like a key/value store: you put named things inside, and later on you ask for them by name and the locator returns them to you.
- An injection container is like a factory: you ask it to produce something and it produces it for you. The specifics of *how* the product is created can range from totally opaque to fully specifiable on your part.

In layman's terms, a service locator can do this:

```
class Perishable
{
    public function __construct(DateTime $expirationDate) { ... }
}

$locator->set('milk', new Perishable(new DateTime());
$milk = $locator->get('milk');
```

but, in contrast to an injection container, it cannot do this:

```
$milk = $container->build(Perishable::class); // ::class is a PHP 5.5 feature
```

An injection container is able to determine *on its own* that `Perishable` has a dependency on a `DateTime` and resolve that dependency. This happens recursively, with the understanding that all the "leaf" dependencies can be instantiated. In this case `DateTime` is easily instantiated because it's a concrete class with a constructor that can run parameterless; in other scenarios you would have to help by telling the container what to do if it comes upon a dependency that cannot be directly instantiated, e.g. an `Iterator`.

> Now, I assume `$host`, `$user`, `$pass` are just string variables, now if I
>   want to pass objects to a controller, how can I dynamically know which
>   objects it needs to have injected?

We have now reached the implementation part: how do you know that a `Perishable` needs a `DateTime`, and how do you create that `DateTime`?

You can do this by using [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Perishable');
$constructor = $class->getConstructor();
$arguments = [];
foreach ($constructor->getParameters() as $parameter) {
    $argumentClass = $parameter->getClass();
    $arguments[] = $argumentClass->newInstance();
}

$result = $class->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
```

This is barebones code that can instantiate a `Perishable` as given above, but of course it will fail badly in more general cases (there's a lot more you have to properly take care of, e.g. recursively resolving constructor arguments).

> Is it right to add an array of types like this?

No, because you would have to violate DRY: the dependencies for `SomeController` would be specified both as part of its constructor definition and when registering it into the container or locator.

> Or is it right to initialize all controllers object in the container when the
>   application loads, then I can easily use any controller?

It's not right at all, and as explained above here you are using the word "container" when in fact you have a mental picture of a service locator. In general, service locator has many drawbacks that an injection container does not. In this situation you should use a proper container instead.